# Python/class-How do I convert this existing program into object-oriented program(Classes)?

Tags: python-3.x, python-class

I wanted to make a program which is CLI based login/register platform. I have made a version of this without using classes;

```
file = open(r"database.txt","a+")

def register():
    print("user is not registered")
    password = input("Set your password: ")
    file.write('\n'+str([name,password]))
    print("user credentials have been successfully saved.")

def login(val):
    status = False
    file.seek(0)
    for line in file:
        cred = eval(line.strip())
        if val == cred[0]:
            status = True
            key = input("enter password: ")
            if key == cred[1]:
                print("Login successfull.")
                break
            else:
                print("Incorrect password.")
    if status == False:
        register()
        

name = input("Enter name: ")
login (name)
file.close()
```

How do I modify this current program into a object-oriented based program which would do the exact same tasks?
login a registered user by verifying him from a database.txt file
and if unregistered storing his details in a text file

---

I tried to make a class structure:

```
file = open(r"database.txt","a+")

class Account():
    def __init__(self,name,password):
        self.name = name
        self.key = password
        # how do I save this instance and its attributes in a text file.
        
def check(name):
    # how do I pull instance attributes from a text file?
    pass

def register():
    user = input("Enter a username: ")
    check(user)
    password = input("set a password: ")
    user = Account(user,password)
    print("user has been successfully registered with the platform.")
    home()

def login():
    user = input("Enter a username: ")
    file.seek(0)
    check(user)        

def home():
    print("Commands: register / login")
    cmd = input("command: ")
    if cmd == "register":
        register()
    elif cmd == "login":
        login()
    else:
        print("invalid command.")
        home()

home()
file.close()
```

Comment: This is an object-oriented program.  If asking how to refactor into a class structure; please let us know what you’ve tried and *exactly* where you’re stuck.

Comment: Okay. I have edited the original post where I have tried to model it into a class structure but stuck at line 7 and 10

Comment: The updated code is not very OO. Consder  creating 2 classes. One for the user account and one that handles the login and account creation.

Comment: From my point of view the much more exciting question compared to *How do i convert code to object oriented one?* is **WHY do you want to convert simple and short code into a longer and more complicated one?** It's like asking how to carry a small backpack using a heavy truck ... Usually it is the other way around: you have a huge amount of code you are loosing control over, so you decide to reduce the redundancy and dependency in code to make its maintenance easier by using the object oriented approach.

Comment: i don't know exactly where the classes are most suitable and I am learning about them. Thankyou for your guidance.